# Why STFT function in MATLABreturns a real number at subband k = fftlength/2?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

guys, my xLt and xRt is two complex audio signal. I set my stft for example：

```
    fftlength=128;
    xLf00 = stft(xLt, fs ,FFTLength=fftlength);
    xRf00 = stft(xRt, fs ,FFTLength=fftlength);
```

I find at k = 64, it returns a real array, where isreal(xLf00(64,：)) returns logical 1.

Is there any method to fix this problem ? It really troubles me a lot.

I am trying to replace that subband by my calculation, but I cannot fit the right T frames number in MATLAB.
For me, I thought T frames at each subbands's size is supposed to be:

```
             M = 96; %window length
             L = 0.75*M; %overlap length
             R = M-L;
             length(xLt) = 8551094;
             NTframes = (length(xLt)-M)/R;
```

MATLAB stft(xLt) returns me a matrix with size(128, 267218), I don't know how to get this 267218 . Obviously, NTframes is not close to 267218.

Comment: PS: my Fs = 48000